# Spring4D - Is it not possible to use Weak<Shared<TObject>>?

Tags: delphi, spring4d

I want to create a connection provider which issues Shared<T> and holds on to a Weak<T> but even though only 1 T instance gets created there are 2 attempts to destroy.

I have included a basic example below.

```
  TMyObj = class
  private
    class var
      fNextId: Integer;
    var
      fId: Integer;
  public
    constructor Create;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  end;

  IProv = interface
  ['{0497DFE9-A77C-4250-82AF-FDA3823A91EC}']
    function Get: Shared<TMyObj>;
    function GetNew: Shared<TMyObj>;
  end;

  TProv = class(TInterfacedObject, IProv)
  private
    fInstance: Weak<TMyObj>;
  protected
    function Get: Shared<TMyObj>;
    function GetNew: Shared<TMyObj>;
  end;

  THolder = class
  private
    fO: Shared<TMyObj>;
  public
    constructor Create(O: Shared<TMyObj>);
  end;

var
  Form2: TForm2;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  var P:=TProv.Create as IProv;

  var H:=THolder.Create(P.Get);
  var H2:=THolder.Create(P.Get);
  FreeAndNil(H);
  FreeAndNil(H2);
  OutputDebugString('End');
end;

{ TMyObj }

constructor TMyObj.Create;
begin
  fId:=InterlockedIncrement(fNextId);
  OutputDebugString(PChar(fId.ToString+' Creating On '+GetCurrentThreadId.ToString));
end;

destructor TMyObj.Destroy;
begin
  OutputDebugString(PChar(fId.ToString+' Destroying On '+GetCurrentThreadId.ToString));
  inherited;
end;

{ TProv }

function TProv.Get: Shared<TMyObj>;
begin
  if fInstance.IsAlive then
    Exit(fInstance.Target);

  Result:=GetNew;
  fInstance:=Result;
end;

function TProv.GetNew: Shared<TMyObj>;
begin
  Result:=TMyObj.Create;
end;

{ THolder }

constructor THolder.Create(O: Shared<TMyObj>);
begin
  fO:=O;
end;
```

I then thought that Weak<T> would only work for interfaces so changed the implementation to hold a Weak<IShared<T>> but then false is returned when I call Weak.IsAlive.

Comment: You cannot create shared instance of the same object twice. Shared takes ownership of the object and will release that object when shared instance goes out of scope.

Comment: `Weak<Shared<T>>` indeed is not possible - `Weak<T>` only supports interfaces (obviously) and objects. It automatically detects when the referenced instance is being destroyed and reports the correct value for `IsAlive`. The defect in your example code results from 2 temp `Shared<TMyObj>` being constructed by the two `.Get` calls. You can see in the debugger that the two `TMyObj.Destroy` attempts are coming from the epilogue of your `Button1Click` method. That is where those two are being finalized and thus they are competing on the ownership to that one `TMyObj` instance.

Comment: Many thanks for the input guys.  I was trying to create a thread specific database connection issuer which would return the same TFDConnection object for any call to the provider in the same thread but not keep the connection alive any longer than required hence the use of Weak<T>.  The idea was to use Spring4D's SingleInstancePerThread for the provider.